# Why does my touch screen have smooth scroll, momentum and elasticity but my Magic Mouse and touch pad do not?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, bluetooth, multi-touch, touchscreen

## Possibly Relevant Facts

- I have a Razer Blade 14 laptop which has a built-in QHD+ touch display.
- I am using Ubuntu 17.04.3 + GNOME 3.24
- I have a Magic Mouse version 1 (and version 2 but that's not what I'm currently using because scrolling does not work at all).

## The Problem

In Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Mouse there are no options to adjust the scroll speed or enable smooth scrolling, momentum or elasticity.

In Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Touchpad there are no options to enable  smooth scrolling or elasticity.

And there are not setting at all for the touch screen.

## The Contradictions

However, despite those features not being available for the mouse or touch pad, when I scroll on my touchscreen I have smooth scrolling, momentum and elastic scrolling.

This suggests to me that the software to apply this to my mouse and touch pad currently exists on my system, but I do not know how to identify where.

As a web-programmer I understand that the software written for the touch screen is probably not directly portable to the mouse and touch pad, but it seems like a start.

## Solution

Does anyone know of any solutions for this problem? And can anyone enlighten me why my touch screen has the support out-of-the-box and yet the mouse and touch pad don't? Keep in mind, my computer came installed with Windows 8.1 - not Linux.